# Powershell OS Count Value Incorrect

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

The idea behind the code is to grab all the computers. Then it filters through the computers and pulls out the OS and OSversions. Then it tests to see if the OS version is inside the array. If the value is there, it will increase it by 1. It the item is not in the array, it will add the item and set the value at 1. However, the results are not as expected. There are over 1000 computers on this network, however, the results only show 2 per OS. The results need to come to a table for other usages.

```
$Adomains = @{}
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties *        
foreach ($ADPC in $Computers) {
    if ($ADPC.OperatingSystem -eq $null) { $os = 'NULL'}
    else { $os = $ADPC.OperatingSystem }
    if ($ADPC.OperatingSystemVersion -eq $null) { $osver = 'NULL'}
    else { $osver = $ADPC.OperatingSystemVersion }
    if ($Adomains."$os - $osver"){
        $Adomains."$os - $osver"++
    } else {
        $Adomains | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "$os - $osver" -Value 1
    }
}
$Adomains
```

Here are the results from the above code:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                                  
Windows Embedded Standard -... 2                                                                                      
Windows 10 Enterprise - 10.... 2                                                                                      
Windows 10 Pro - 10.0 (17134)  2                                                                                      
Windows 10 Enterprise - 10.... 2                                                                                      
Windows 8.1 Pro - 6.3 (9600)   2                                                                                      
Windows 10 Pro - 10.0 (16299)  2                                                                                      
unknown - unknown              2                                                                                      
Windows 10 Enterprise - 10.... 2                                                                                      
Windows 10 Pro - 10.0 (14393)  2                                                                                      
Windows 10 Pro - 10.0 (15063)  2                                                                                      
Windows 7 Professional - 6.... 2                                                                                      
Windows 10 Pro - 10.0 (10586)  2
```

I am trying to figure out where my logic error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is IMO overcomplicated.

```
$Adomains = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion | 
    Group-Object OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion -NoElement
$Adomains | Format-Table -Autosize
```

**EDITED as per [Bacon Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696808/bacon-bits) helpful hint**

Comment: `$Adomains | Format-Table -Autosize` might be useful to provide more readable output since the default formatter truncates after 20 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Focused the code down and sorted only by the unique OSes and placed an if statement that solves the "$Null" objects.

```
        $OSes = Get-ADComputer -Filter {enabled -eq $true} -Properties operatingsystem | sort operatingsystem 
        $Unique = ($OSes | select operatingsystem -Unique).Operatingsystem
        $Return = @()
        foreach ($U in $Unique) {
            $ADOScounting = ($OSes | Where-Object {$_.OperatingSystem -like "$U"}).count
            $return += [pscustomobject][ordered] @{
                Name = $U 
                Count = if ($ADOScounting -eq $null) {"0"} else {$ADOScounting}
            }
        }
        $Return
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original error multifaceted. First, you're using a hashtable, not an array (which seems to be intended, you just got the term wrong).

The main source of your issue is that when you first try to add a new OS, you're not adding a new key/value pair, you're adding a property to the hashtable object itself.

You a use `.` to access both properties and in the case of hashtables, entries.

So what happens after you add the property the first time, is that when the code comes around to check for existence with `if ($Adomain."$os - $osver")` the result is `$true`; so far so good.

Then you do `$Adomains."$os - $osver"++` and this is where it gets weird.

The *read* of the value comes from the property, so it's `1`. The *write* creates a new entry in the hashtable with value of 2 (the `1` from the property plus `1`). Now the property is `1`, the entry value is `2`.

Next time around though, this happens again, the read comes from the property, and the write goes to the entry, so you perpetually write `2`.

To solve it in your code with minimal effort, change this:

```
} else {
    $Adomains | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "$os - $osver" -Value 1
}
```

to this:

```
} else {
    $Adomains."$os - $osver" = 1
}
```

---

But even better is to use `Group-Object`, which already does what you want:

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties OperatingSystem,OperatingSystemVersion | 
    Group-Object -Property {"$($_.OperatingSystem) - $($_.OperatingSystemVerson)"}
```

It doesn't convert null values to a prettier string, but you can put that logic inside the scriptblock if you want to.

It returns group objects, but you can add `-AsHashTable -AsString` if you want a real hashtable returned.